# HostGator not allowing END flag in .htaccess files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

After developing my site using WAMP, I went to put my site on HostGator and I got a 500 internal server error. I tried incrementally removing things from my .htaccess file and discovered that I only get this when the END flag occurs anywhere in the file. Why won't they allow this? It worked fine as a virtual host when developing with WAMP.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you ask *them*? What would we know about the intentions of your hoster?

Comment: The END flag exists since Apache 2.3... What is the Apache version used ?

Comment: Ah that would be why. Thanks. HostGator uses 2.2.25.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache 2.2, which doesn't have the `END` rewrite flag, you'll have to add this to the very top of your rules to prevent looping:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```